# Only allowing certain characters

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of creating a form and I wish to validate the input fields onKeyPress. I have managed to find JavaScript to restrict a field to only allowing numbers to be entered. Now I am trying to adapt that code to only allow letters and a hyphens to be allowed.

The code I have to only allow numbers is as follows...

```
     function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
```

How would I adapt and change this to only allow letters and hyphens instead.

Sorry if this question has been asked  before but all I can find is doing it using Jquery etc. and I would like to try and avoid that if I can.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use key events like this is a bad idea because a value can be entered without dispatching a suitable event and it's very annoying for users. You only care about the value when it's sent to the server or wherever, so let the user create a valid value any way that suits them, then validate it at the point that it needs to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myRegex = /^[A-Za-z\-]+$/;

myRegex.test('hello'); //true
myRegex.test('asdasd-adasd'); //true
myRegex.test('123as'); //false
```

Comment: Consider `!/[^a-z\-]/i.test(string)`. ;-)